# how to create a custom 500 error page in opencart

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, .htaccess, opencart

I want to create a custom 500 ethir offer in opencart for my website. I am using Apache.

I have tried htaccess errorDocument method and try catch also but didn't worked for me. If there is any functionality available in opencart please suggest or any other method are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find .htaccess file and place a string

   ```
   ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
   ```
2. Create */errors* directory in website root folder
3. Place there file 500.html with a HTML and CSS

There is a best way to do.

What error appears with using *ErrorDocument* directive?